# How to use Tiles in Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

My tiles.xml file looks like

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
    <tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="homepage" template="/layouts/classic.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/tile1.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/body.jsp" />
    </definition>
    </tiles-definitions>`

I created a classic.jsp which is the master layout

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>  
<td>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />    
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And i created tile1.jsp and body.jsp 

I included these jar in WEB-INF/lib 

`commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar
servlet-api.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
tiles-servlet-wildcard-2.2.2.jar
tiles-template-2.2.2.jar`

What to add in web.xml related to tiles?

Comment: You don't need a solution, you need a tutorial. Google 'Tiles tutorial' .

Answer (score 0):

You need a view resolver and a tiles configurer

```
<bean id="viewResolverTiles"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```